# PowerShell script that launches a user-defined process using a temporary user profile created/removed every time its launch

Tags: powershell

Design and develop a PowerShell script that launches a user-defined process using a temporary user profile created/removed every time its launch.

Required output format:
ProcessPath ProcessUserName

Example output:

c:\windows\notepad.exe      TestUser

c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe AnotherUser

c:\windows\system32\mspaint.exe
                                               YetAnotherUser

Please help me out , cus I have no much knowledge in powershell. ... please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
Switch ($env:username) {
  'User1' { notepad ; break}
  'User2' { calc ; break}
   Default {}
}
```

Comment: thanks allot., but em not able to see the out put as i was expecting... i may be wrong because i don't much about power shell . after running the Script i pressed Enter but i dint got any out put. can you please suggest me how to get the required out put.    can i get the same in C# also.., i know C# a bit more then powershell , Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You must specify the correct username: 'user1', 'user2'..etc.